# Task executed in Spring cloud data flow server doesn't see data on postgres database

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm implementing an Spring Batch application that connects to a postgres database and after that it connects to an API to retrieve data. I've executed my code locally and it works perfect, but when I create a task to integrate it with Spring Cloud Data Flow, the data from the tables in the database is empty (when they are not really empty, and when I execute it locally works fine).

The application running on Spring Cloud Data Flow can connect to the database, and I can see the tables, but they are always empty. The execution runs no errors, it just can't see the data that are on the tables.

I edit the post to say that both spring cloud data flow and postgres database are docker images that im running on my computer.

I have my connection configured as follows in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres1
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.batch.initialize-schema: always
```

What could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see how/why the tables are created correctly but remain empty after the task execution. If you can provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, we can try to take a look.

Comment: I have encountered the solution. When I get my Spring cloud data flow docker up, I do it with dataflow3 database, which is inside my postgres docker. When I configue the task, I define that I need to use postgres1 database, which is also inside my postgres docker. I don't know why the task ignores the configuration for use postgres1 database and uses the one that is specified for Spring Cloud Data Flow docker.